# AnyLogic: Is there a way to specify array of decision variables in Optimization Experiment?

Tags: optimization, anylogic

I am working on an optimization model using AnyLogic. Is there a way to specify an array of decision variables in AnyLogic like how it is in IBM Cplex? For lesser number of decision variables (say 2 to 5), I used to specify them individually, for example, numAgents_1, numAgents_2 for locations 1 and 2. However, as my model grows in size and more locations are added (up to 40), is there a way I can specify them as an array or list of decision variables?

Any help regarding this would be really useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you need to use a "custom experiment" instead and set it up using an Array of decision variables.

This is not totally straight forward, however, best start by checking the example models that apply custom experiments.

Some starting points below:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I will go through the custom experiment example models.